# finding right port to connect to skype database

Tags: perl, port, skype, dbi, freetds

I am trying to connect to a Sybase database with metadata about Skype called `skype2`. The code in in Perl, and I'm use the DBI module to connect.

Here is my code:

```
  my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Sybase:server=skype2;database=*****", 'user', 'pass', {PrintError => 1});
```

I've set up a `[skype2]` DSN in `freetds.conf`, located in `/etc`:

```
[skype2]
    host = **.**.**.**
    port = 49396
    tds version = 7.0
```

The problem is that I need to find the port dynamically through a database query (here, it is 49396). Should I use netstat to connect and search for the proper port, or is there a better way?

Thank you for your response.

Comment: Is this about the Microsoft chat software Skype?

Comment: @simbabque i dont know exactly.i use this database to find all skype calls happen for a specific comoany!

Comment: I take it you mean Sybase, not MySQL, as that's what the driver name says? So it seems your ops decided to run the database server on a nonstandard port and you just have to connect to it. As they probably won't be changing port assignments every day it sounds reasonable to find the port once and change the config file accordingly. Actually this should be documented somewhere so you don't have to monkey around with netstat ...

Comment: FreeTDS can be used to connect to SQL Server or Sybase. First, find out which one, because that will affect what TDS version you should use. As for finding the port, getting it documented and standardized is the way to go. Using netstat or something like that will likely end in pitchforks, torches, and tears!

Comment: @FlipperPA 
 yes its Sybase.port is documented but in real world it first connect to that port then been negotiate to right port and here is where freetds cant work so i have to find the negotiated port manually.i asked for better way!

Comment: @mbethke plx read the above reply.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to connect to a database to find the port of the secondary database. You can provide the `PORT` as part of the connection string, even as a variable. Here's an example connection string which should help:

```
my $port = "1433";
my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:ODBC:DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=yourfullserver.com;PORT=' . $port . ';DATABASE=yourdbname;TDS_Version=7.2', 'user', 'password', {PrintError => 1});
```

That'll let you connect to a dynamic port. So, connect to your first server, get the port number you need from the DB and save it to a variable, then connect to the second database. Good luck!